# Can free Heroku accounts do web scraping without url limitations?

Tags: heroku

Tried to create a support ticket on a free Heroku account but...
[image]

My question is if a free Heroku account has any restrictions on light web scraping (10 requests/week max).
I know that a free PythonAnywhere account has some url restrictions for web scraping but no restrictions at all for a paid account. If a free Heroku account has no limitations, I would immediately switch to Heroku to run my Flask app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware there is no limit that would apply here on Heroku. Given it is a free tier why not just deploy and see?